# Good or bad database design

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have following migration:

```
create table(:countries_codes) do

  add :iso, :string, size: 2
  add :name, :string

  timestamps
end
create unique_index(:countries_codes, [:iso])

create table(:languages_codes) do

  add :iso, :string, size: 2
  add :name, :string

  timestamps

end
create unique_index(:languages_codes, [:iso])

create table(:countries) do

  add :country_iso_id,  references(:countries_codes)
  add :language_iso_id, references(:languages_codes)
  add :name, :string

  timestamps
end
create unique_index(:countries, [:country_iso_id, :language_iso_id])
```

Would be it better to make `iso` field on `countries_codes` and `languages_codes` as primary key, disable auto generated `id` field?

```
create table(:languages_codes, primary_key: false) do

  add :iso, :string, size: 2, primary_key: true
  add :name, :string

  timestamps

end

create table(:countries, primary_key: false) do

  add :country_iso,  references(:countries_codes, column: :iso, type: :string), primary_key: true
  add :language_iso, references(:languages_codes, column: :iso, type: :string), primary_key: true
  add :name, :string

  timestamps
end

create table(:countries_codes, primary_key: false) do

  add :iso, :string, size: 2, primary_key: true
  add :name, :string

  timestamps
end
```

Comment: I think "better" is a relative term here and different people will prefer to do different things based on their needs. Because of that, I am voting to close this because I think answers will be based on opinion.

Comment: Try looking at the Wikipedia article on surrogate keys (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) for some of the benefits and drawbacks of both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"better" is subjective, but there is no point in an auto-generated ID when there is already a naturally unique and reasonably short value.  Make the codes the primary key and avoid the auto-generated IDs.

Comment: I have met some database experts who would disagree with you. Google "surrogate key" to see what I mean.  See especially this (from the Wikipedia article on this): ``Having the key independent of all other columns insulates the database relationships from changes in data values or database design (making the database more agile) and guarantees uniqueness.``

Comment: I agree with you on that.  What we assume is unique now might not be unique later, and the surrogate keys help avoiding the cascading changes to the system when changes must be made.  I just prefer adding complexity only when needed and making sure the rest of the system is easily changed when the initial assumptions do not hold true.  But I tend to operate in places where all code is under our control and we can deploy all code affected.

Comment: That's a fair observation Dan.  Too many of us put in "just in case" complexity and prematurely overcomplicate problems.